# javascript: how to remove data from array

Tags: javascript

From below code i tried removing  data from array. Unfortunately  Its not removing  data from my array i.e `ary` , See if  you can help me with this challange

```
var ary = [{"Force":"Force Converter"},{"Power":"Power Converter"}];

 function removeFav(n,v){ 
       var index = ary.indexOf(n);
       alert(index);
       if (index > -1) {
           ary.splice(index, 1);
        }
         alert("New updated Array:"+ary);
   }
```

Calling to remove as

```
removeFav("Power","Power Converter");  // this calls the above method
```

Comment: Why does your method take a `v` argument that it never uses?

Comment: as written, you need to pass the object in the array, not a string describing the object.

Comment: @IanKemp  thats not a problem. This code is part of my huge application.   Keeping `v` in there for now does not makes diffrence

Comment: @dandavis How can we do so?

Comment: like `removeFav(ary[0])`, which is kinda not very helpful really...

Comment: @dandavis confused !! what do you mean?

Comment: i mean that it doesn't make sense to not use splice() when you have the index right there (passing ary[0]). if the object had a different name, then removeFav makes a lot more sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is essentially calling `ary.indexOf("Power")`. But there is no element in `ary` with the index `Power`, hence why the call always fails. In fact, `Array.indexOf()` won't work for your scenario because it only works on simple types, not complex objects.

What you need to do is check for an object *with the specified key* in that array, and remove said object if it's found. For this you use the `Object.hasOwnProperty()`method:

```
function removeFav(key) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i ++) {
    // if the current array item has a property
    // that matches the specified one, remove that item
    if (ary[i].hasOwnProperty(key)){
      ary.splice(i, 1);
      return;
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ashutosh correct, I just prefer to use variable names that make code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for ur explanation. And after this if i do `localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(ary));` then it will update new array ,right?

Comment: HI, I got new problem, How can i make array to accept only unique item ? i wrote a boolen method here to check but its not working, can you check this here plz http://jsfiddle.net/pewn1d4m/9/

Answer (score 1):

Note: browser support for indexOf is limited, it is not supported in IE7-8.

Here is a demo [Demo](http://jsbin.com/cayiyo/2/edit?html,output) and below you can find the code again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        localStorage.clear();

        var ary = [];
        ary.push({ "Force": "Force Converter" })
        ary.push({ "Power": "Power Converter" });

        function contains(arr, k) {
            var doesContain = false;
            for (var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
                var item = arr[i];
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    doesContain = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return doesContain;
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem("testObject") != null) {
            alert("localstorage has item testobject");
            //Parse the retrieved value into an array
            ary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
        }

        function setFavorite(k, v) {

            var obj = {};
            obj[k] = v;

            var hasItem = contains(ary, k);

            if (!hasItem) {
                ary.push(obj);
                // Put the object into storage
                localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(ary));
            }


            // Retrieve the object from storage
            var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

            // Parse the retrieved value into an array
            var retrievedArray = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

            // clear the ouput first
            $("#fab-id").html("");
            //iterate over the array which contains key-value pairs
            for (var i = 0; i < retrievedArray.length; i++) {
                var item = retrievedArray[i];

                var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
                var value = item[key];

                //----------BELOW CODE DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY----   
                $("#fab-id").append('<a>' + value + '</a><br/>');

            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Click me!</button>
    <button id="btn2">Add another item!</button>

    <div id="fab-id"></div>

    <script>
        //adding a simple click event handler
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            //setFavorite("Power", "Power Converter");
            //setFavorite("Power", "Power Converter");
            setFavorite("propA", "X");
        });

        document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function () {
            //setFavorite("Power", "Power Converter");
            //setFavorite("Power", "Power Converter");
            setFavorite("xyz", "blabal");
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i declare ary like this:
 var ary = [{"Force":"Force Converter"},{"Power":"bar"}];
and call the function:
removeFav("Power","Power Converter"); 
it will remove it.

your condition should be
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(n) && obj[n]===v)

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` means?

Comment: checks if the object has that property

Comment: @Legends what OMAR ELAWADY is saying in coment?

Comment: @Ashutosh ask him ;-)

Comment: :D I'm saying that you are comparing the keys only and not comparing the values so removeFav("Power","wqrfds");  will remove the second object

Comment: np, this example works in this way, but if you want it to work differently, you have to specify it in your question ;-)

Comment: @Legends HI, I got new problem, How can i make array to accept only unique item ? i wrote a boolen method here to check but its not working, can you check this here plz http://jsfiddle.net/pewn1d4m/9/

Comment: @Legends only the name should be unique is suffiecent for me

Comment: see my answer below ;-)

Comment: @Donkey I have updated the answer, my fault it was incorrect.
The code only checks if the property supplied to "setFavorite" exists in any object already contained in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your contains function is perfect.
This should work for you, just use the name directly as property

```
function setFavorite(name, value){
 alert(contains(ary, value));

    var obj = {}; 
    obj.name = value; 
    alert(obj.name);
    ary.push(obj);
    alert(contains(ary, obj));
```

Comment: thanks for your time.  i do want to add it in the array , if already exists, here we are writing the `contains` alert after` ary.push..`

Comment: + One given .. ...becoz i already accepted answer for this question yesterday

Comment: Donkey Donkey, two many errors, make yourself comfortable with javascript first, wait I will change the script ..... aaaaa

Comment: Hi, http://jsfiddle.net/pewn1d4m/12/  still struggling, its not working as we expected

Comment: Did you take a look at the demo in the answer below: I changed the code a bit, so you only have to pass the property to the Contains function.
http://jsbin.com/cayiyo/2/

Comment: Thank god. Finally Donkey got solution :)